# What's wrong with this MySQL query -- db won't accept?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO 12:12:12:12:12(timestamp,niceTime,temperature,relative_humidity,wind_speed,gust_speed,rain_mm_per_hour,nsew,str,ip) VALUES(1361707978,'2013-02-24T12:12:58+00:00',0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,'1010101010101010','0')
```

The name of the table is "12:12:12:12:12".

Here is the schema:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$mac` (
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `niceTime` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `temperature` float NOT NULL,
  `relative_humidity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wind_speed` float NOT NULL,
  `gust_speed` float NOT NULL,
  `rain_mm_per_hour` float NOT NULL,
  `nsew` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `str` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;"
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the query to be accepted ;(

```
Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:12:12:12:12(timestamp,niceTime,temperature,relative_humidity,wind_speed,gust_' at line 1
```

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Quote the table name like you do in the create table statement. But really this smells of bad design. Do you really want one table per MAC address you're tracking?

Comment: Yep. There are about 1000 computers feeding weather data to a central database. One table per MAC address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks around identifiers, especially when using such unconventional table names:

```
INSERT INTO `12:12:12:12:12`(timestamp,niceTime,temperature,relative_humidity,wind_speed,gust_speed,rain_mm_per_hour,nsew,str,ip)
VALUES(1361707978,'2013-02-24T12:12:58+00:00',0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,'1010101010101010','0')
```

Answer (score 4):

you will use backticks like that to your table name 
 12:12:12:12:12

try this

```
   INSERT INTO `12:12:12:12:12`(timestamp,niceTime,temperature,relative_humidity,wind_speed,gust_speed,rain_mm_per_hour,nsew,str,ip) VALUES(1361707978,'2013-02-24T12:12:58+00:00',0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,'1010101010101010','0'
```

EDIT.

Rules for naming objects, including tables in MySql:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but
>   unless quoted may not consist solely
>   of digits.

```
The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):
```